# Any tool to suggest unit reference automatically for Delphi 2010?

Tags: delphi, reference, autocomplete, delphi-2010, delphi-units

MS Visual Studio has a great feature: it automatically suggests the units to add in `using` clause when you typing the code with refrences to absent standard classes.

Is there any 3-rd party tool to implement similar feature for Delphi?

I'm tired to add all those SysUtils, Windows, Messages etc in each new unit.

Comment: +1 That's a great feature in VS that is sorely lacking in RAD Studio

Comment: +1 what David said + it shouldn't be too complicated to parse all units from "paths" and store them in a sqlite db or something light so that when you press CTRL+SPACE and type something that's not related to units already included, it should show options like "declare type|class|etc." or "include unit X" if it finds what you're typing...

Comment: When you use code completion the unit will be added when it's not already there. So it is possible.

Comment: in Win7 (and may be Vista) you can add *.pas files to indexing in Control Panel.. so after typing for exmaple `WM_CLOSE` in start menu search string you will get some results.. of course it's not tool for delphi.. but it is handy to find needed units;
see screenshot: http://img204.imageshack.us/img204/7278/123qav.png

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the unit which contains the reference is not yet in the uses list, this is how I save many manual steps:

- right-click on the underlined (error-insighted) text
- choose “Refactoring | Find Unit…“.

A dialog will present the available unit which contains the unknown type or symbol, and a mouse click adds the selected unit to the uses list of the current file.

Comment: Can I change/extend the browsing paths?

Comment: This blows up with out of memory in XE5 Update 2 :-( My method for RTL functions: press F1 on the identifier and copy & paste the unit they are in.

Comment: Doesn't always work: will not find Winapi.MMSystem for PlaySound function.

Answer (score 3):

[The JCL](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JEDI_Code_Library) includes the "Uses Wizard." It watches for compilation errors mentioning "Undeclared identifier," and when it sees one, it automatically adds the unit where that identifier is declared.

The package *JclUsesExpert.dpk* is only available for certain Delphi versions. I don't know if that's because the plug-in doesn't work in later versions, or if someone merely neglected to copy the project into later versions' folders.

Answer (score 2):

CNPack Input Helper can sugest and autocomplete units (sorry for another answer, but I can't comment other).

CNPack unfortunately don't auto-add units from place of code input but you can:

- Copy a word from cursor place (CNPack->Editor enchancements->Tabset/Button->Clipboard operations->Cut/copy token...).
- Eventually search this word in source files (grep) to identify unit.
- Use CNPack->Toggle Uses/Include Field (Ctrl+u) and start typing and use CNPack->Input Helper sugestion/autocompletion, or IDE/GExperts/CNPack use unit future
- Back to place of code edition

Comment: I can't understand how to use this Input Helper for suggestion which units to include into `uses` clause. Can you explain your scenario?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a tool to suggest references, it only cleans up unneeded unit clauses.

CnPack IDE Wizards is an excellent opensource plugin for Delphi.
http://www.cnpack.org/index.php?lang=en

I use its `Uses cleaner` feature a lot.
There is a menu item:
<kbd>CnPack</kbd>-><kbd>Project Enhancements</kbd>-><kbd>Use Unit</kbd>

I think this can be helpful for your needs.

Comment: nope. it can help in managing existed references, but cannot suggest references.

Comment: @hubalu, but this question is about unit suggestion. When you type for instance `ShellExecute` then you'll get `ShellAPI` unit suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe you can try this:
http://www.epocalipse.com/products.htm

Unit Expert

"A freeware Delphi add-in that allows you to quickly open units and also add them to the uses clause."

I never tried this expert but it semms promising.

Answer (score 0):

The [rFindUnit IDE extension](https://github.com/rfrezino/RFindUnit) is the enhanced version of built-in "Refactoring | Find Unit…" function suggested by @mjn above.